# Setup a doublex spy returning different values in each invocation

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, spy

I want to test the handling of request retries in our codebase. For that I want to define a `spy` which is returning different values for the same invocation. I am using [doublex](http://python-doublex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and [py.test](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) for my testing:

This is the working testcase, for a single invocation:

```
import pytest
from doublex import Spy, assert_that, ANY_ARG, is_


@pytest.mark.unit
def test__me():

    with Spy() as spy:
        spy.foo(ANY_ARG).returns(10)

    assert_that(spy.foo(), is_(10))
```

The retries will be performed by doing the exact same calls (that is, with the same arguments), but will be returning different values. It would be something similar to this (which does not work):

```
import pytest
from doublex import Spy, assert_that, ANY_ARG, is_


@pytest.mark.unit
def test__me():

    # TODO: how to setup a spy returning changing values, with fixed calling arguments?
    with Spy() as spy:
        spy.foo(ANY_ARG).returns(10)
        spy.foo(ANY_ARG).returns(11)

    # Each invocation will return a different value
    assert_that(spy.foo(), is_(10))
    assert_that(spy.foo(), is_(11))
```

How can I setup a spy which returns a different value with each invocation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.delegates()`](http://python-doublex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/delegates.html) instead of `.returns()`:

```
with Stub() as stub:
    stub.foo().delegates([1, 2, 3])

assert_that(stub.foo(), is_(1))
assert_that(stub.foo(), is_(2))
assert_that(stub.foo(), is_(3))
```

Note that calling `stub.foo()` a fourth time above would raise `StopIteration`. To avoid that, you can pass a function instead of a list to `.delegates()`.